# C# CheckBox Checked value cannot change if clicked manually on the form

Tags: c#, checkbox

So I do loop over the form and check "checked" value for all checkboxes. Every time I get "Unchecked" back even if the checkbox is checked on the form.

here is how i loop

```
   public  class FindAll
{
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(Control root)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Control>();
        stack.Push(root);

        while (stack.Any())
        {
            var next = stack.Pop();
            foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
                stack.Push(child);
            yield return next;
        }
    }
}
```

and here how i determine checked state

```
public List<string> Checked()
    {
        List<string> checkedList = new List<string>();
        var all = new FindAll();
        foreach (var checkbox in all.GetAllChildren(tabPage4).OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            checkedList.Add(checkbox.CheckState.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(checkedList.ElementAt(i));
        }
        return checkedList;
    }
```

no matter if i chech the checkboxes on the form while app is running. i always get "unchecked" value.

Comment: Same happens if I use .checked instead of .checkstate

Comment: Checked the same code and found working as expected. It is giving me correct results.

Comment: are you sure you are looping and checking on the same `Form` ?

Comment: i'm sending "tabpage4" to this method. I get correct checkboxes (checked by name) somehow i can set "checked" ptoperty programatically but not by hand

Comment: I think loop returns objects as "Control" whereas I check property of checkbox. this property is lost when returning "control". let me see...

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoded:

```
foreach (Control c in tabPage4.Controls)
{
    if (c is GroupBox)
    {
        foreach (Control d in c.Controls)
        {
            var e = d as CheckBox;
            if (e != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(d.Name + "  " + e.Checked);
                checkedList.Add(d.Name, e.Checked.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```